# How to add the date manually using jquery date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I need to add the Date manually in text box using jquery date picker. For example I enter the text '1 1 14' in text box after tab its need to be take the 1/1/2014. its possible or not? using jquery...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're gonna need this: http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/

Comment: oh my goodness, in my site shows web page block any other link...?